# ¿Cómo seleccionar los registros con la fecha actual y hora de apertura más reciente?

Tags: mysql, sql

No se me ocurre como realizar la siguiente consulta sql.
Estoy utilizando MySql como gestor de base de datos y tengo una tabla llamada comandas la cual contiene información de las comandas de un restaurante.

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+---------+------------+
| CODIGOCOMANDA | IDUSUARIO | CODIGOMESA | FECHA      | HORADEAPERTURA | HORADECIERRE | ESTADO         | IMPORTE | TIPODEPAGO |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+---------+------------+
| 281           | 23        | 1          | 2018-11-10 | 00:33:50       | NULL         | En preparación | NULL    | NULL       |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+---------+------------+
| 280           | 23        | 2          | 2018-11-10 | 00:32:46       | NULL         | En preparación | NULL    | NULL       |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+---------+------------+
| 282           | 23        | 1          | 2018-11-10 | 00:43:53       | NULL         | Abierta        | NULL    | NULL       |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+---------+------------+
| 278           | 23        | 1          | 2018-11-09 | 23:27:47       | 23:46:12     | Pagada         | NULL    | Tarjeta    |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+---------+------------+
```

Y quiero que me devuelva de cada CODIGOMESA el registro con fecha del día actual(es decir para hoy fecha 10/11/2018) y hora de apertura más reciente, pero que no se repita el codigomesa. Es decir debería quedar así

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+---------+------------+
| CODIGOCOMANDA | IDUSUARIO | CODIGOMESA | FECHA      | HORADEAPERTURA | HORADECIERRE | ESTADO         | IMPORTE | TIPODEPAGO |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+---------+------------+
| 280           | 23        | 2          | 2018-11-10 | 00:32:46       | NULL         | En preparación | NULL    | NULL       |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+---------+------------+
| 282           | 23        | 1          | 2018-11-10 | 00:43:53       | NULL         | Abierta        | NULL    | NULL       |
+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+---------+------------+
```

¿Cómo podría realizar la consulta?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL moderno, puedes hacerlo facilmente valiéndote de la [función de ventana](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) [`row_number()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/):

El query quedaría algo como:

```
select *
  from (select *, row_number() over (partition by codigomesa order by horadeapertura desc) numeroFila
          from ComoSeLlameTuTabla
         where Fecha = '2018-11-10'
       ) q1
 where numeroFila = 1;
```

Esto te va a traer una columna adicional llamada `numerofila`, que puedes excluir del select si incluyes todos los nombres de los campos.

Lo que estoy haciendo es, en una *tabla derivada* voy calculando el número de fila para cada comanda de cada mesa, creando particiones por la columna `codigomesa`. Para cada partición, voy numerando las filas ordenando de forma descendente por `horadeapertura`.

Finalmente, en mi query principal, traigo solamente aquellas comandas cuyo numero de fila sea 1, que es la última comanda de cada mesa.

Un saludo.

Comment: Al probarlo da el siguiente error  #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '(partition by codigomesa order by horadeapertura desc) numeroFila
          fro' en la linea 2. No sé si es por la versión de mySql, ¿Se podría hacer sin usar row_number?